# Hibernate Criteria createalias with max created date

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entity like

```java
POrder {
    private Long id;
    private Long total;
    private List<OrderComment> comments;
    // ...
}

OrderComment {
    private Long id;
    private POrder order;
    // ...
    private Date created;
}
```

I want to write a criteria which selects orders on which most recent comment is equal to "some comment".

Comment: could you please explain more?

Comment: Subquery for `max(created) from OrderComment`